# Internet Push Notification In React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, cross-platform, react-notifications

How can I make the app to send a notification when the user connected to the internet after being disconnected even when the app is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `"@react-native-community/netinfo"` library to check whether the internet is connected or not and based on that you can configure the push notification using `react-native-push-notification` library.

[Click here](https://dev.to/adriantwarog/how-to-perform-local-push-notifications-on-react-native-without-remote-providers-like-firebase-or-onesignal-4034) for the reference!

Well I will recommend to use the alerts to notify the user wether the internet is lost or back based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response gonna check it, I wanted to use push notification because I needed when the app is closed.